# Inconsistent PWA URL/toolbar experience. Can't remove on Apple devices

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

I'm working toward adding PWA functionality to a web app for a client. However, I'm getting variattions between my test app and my implementation. on all apple devices, my client app has a readonly url bar that I cannot seem to get rid of. I created a stand alone test app with angular and added on the pwa functionality using Angular's pwa package as outlined [here](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started).

Here are the varying results. test app is on the left, and client app is on the right:

The apps as the appear install on my mac
[image]

The supporting manifest files
[image]

As far as I can tell everything is the same but I'm getting different results. What am I missing?

The only difference I can think of to explore at the moment are the hosting environments. The test app is on netlify and the client app is on an AWS setup through CloudFront.

Here are the headers that are being returned by the index page for each:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to the manifest file not living on root of the site. It was instead inside of an `offline` folder.